# 3D diagram z-range are odd

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I have the following code which I took from an example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots,pgfplotstable}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\pgfplotstableread{
plot1   plot2   plot3   plot4
0       0       0       0
3.466   2.058   0       0
4.262   2.976   0.001   0
3.822   3.168   0.006   0.008
2.953   2.936   0.019   0.063
2.065   2.492   0.046   0.265
1.332   1.977   0.092   0.734
0.797   1.478   0.164   1.508
0.443   1.045   0.268   2.44
0.228   0.698   0.412   3.219
0.107   0.438   0.598   3.524
0.046   0.256   0.831   3.219
0.017   0.138   1.109   2.44
0.006   0.067   1.429   1.508
0.002   0.029   1.78    0.734
0       0.01    2.141   0.265
0       0.003   2.479   0.063
0       0.001   2.736   0.008
0       0       2.808   0
0       0       2.465   0
0       0       0       0
}\dummydata

\begin{axis}[
    samples=30,
    domain=-4:4,
    samples y=0, ytick={1,...,4},
    zmin=0,
    area plot/.style={
        fill opacity=0.75,
        draw=orange!80!black,thick,
        fill=orange,
        mark=none,
    }
]
\pgfplotsinvokeforeach{4,3,...,1}{
    \addplot3 [area plot] table [x expr=\coordindex, y expr=#1, z=plot#1] {\dummydata};
}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Which results into this:[image]

So I just started using it and feeding my data:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots,pgfplotstable}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\pgfplotstableread{
plot1   plot2   plot3   plot4
33747   33106   32755   32930
33509   32593   34302   33049
33872   32091   34332   33215
33019   32247   34372   33256
33120   32625   32874   33547
33177   34026   34586   33158
32875   35361   34835   33125
33118   33176   31211   33604
34313   34541   33225   32763
32968   32928   33855   33702
33086   33252   31636   34113
34200   33695   32812   33003
32568   33940   32663   40287
32656   32893   34264   20548
33318   35521   34196   41851
32601   29895   33255   33100
34217   34852   33790   34922
33149   33691   31934   31673
34077   32532   33860   32766
32832   34082   33221   33544
32835   33256   33164   33222
32746   33081   32762   31282
33962   32996   33580   33369
32896   33818   33053   36396
33168   32747   33373   31252
33680   33286   38413   35094
32870   33949   21930   28687
33661   35410   38583   35524
34272   31062   33643   34092
33488   33348   33521   32926
}\dummydata

\begin{axis}[
    samples=30,
    domain=-4:4,
    samples y=0, ytick={1,...,4},
    zmin=0,
    area plot/.style={
        fill opacity=0.75,
        draw=orange!80!black,thick,
        fill=orange,
        mark=none,
    }
]
\pgfplotsinvokeforeach{4,3,...,1}{
    \addplot3 [area plot] table [x expr=\coordindex, y expr=#1, z=plot#1] {\dummydata};
}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

But this is what I get:
[image]

Where is the problem?

Comment: Not an answer but a workaround: try adding as the first and last row of your dataset `0 0 0 0`. This fixes the issue.

Comment: @Alexander It kinda works around it yes. Thanks it is something at least :)

Comment: What Alexander did is what actually makes it work. pgfplots is drawing a line between the final and the first point to create an area to paint. If you don't have those then it draws through your data points. What do you want to have?

Comment: Can I fake it by restricting one axis? So that the last and first value do not show

Comment: For me its unclear what you are asking. Please clarify your specific problem. You added different data, why?(just as example?) Does `xmin=0, xmax=20,xtick={0,5,...,20},` solve your problem with x axis?